# Probability of two sets of results being tied to the same $P$

Tags: probability

Let's say we have $2$ loaded coins, $C_1$ and $C_2$, with unknown probabilities $p_1$ and $p_2$ of getting heads.

- Tossing $C_1$ $30$ times yields $0$ heads and $30$ tails
- Tossing $C_2$ $20$ times yields $5$ heads and $15$ tails.

The questions, then, are:

1. What would be the probability of $p_1$ and $p_2$ being equal?
2. If they were equal, would their value be estimated by $0.1$? ($5$ heads out of $50$ total tosses) if not, why?
3. If different, how likely is it that $P_1$ is equal to $0$? (or a very marginal number, like < $10^{-5}$).

**Context**: Couple of days ago I was playing a game involving fishing (Fantasy Life on Nintendo 3DS, if anyone's interested), completing fishing quests and requirements for ingame progress.

I was at a certain spot that reportedly has only two species of fish: Sardines, and (more rarely) Pufferfishes. The probability of getting puffers is unknown although it is known to be affected by ingame parameters such as a LUCK stat (that was left unchanged that day).

Couple of hours in, I get $5$ puffers and $45$ sardines, $50$ in total.
The first $30$ fishes were all sardines, then after a certain ingame event (my fishing skill rose by $1$), I  got $5$ puffers among the remaining $20$ fishes. No other parameters were changed.

I wish to know with how much certainty I can claim that the fishing skill did affect the drop rate? And how likely is it that that skill up was a requirement, meaning that the probability before that was a flat $0$.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: @Shaun so should the OP just ommit the other questions or split them over multiple posts which doesn't make sense because they are all related? You can try to solve one at a time, no pressure, and then let them know about your progress.

Comment: The OP is best off asking them as separate questions, @mohamedshawky, linking to each other.

Comment: I'm mainly interested in the first one, the rest i came up with while editing my question

Comment: Hi @Dleep, for this question to make sense you will need to define a probability distribution over the probabilities $(p_1, p_2)$.  Otherwise, the question is ambiguous.  For example, what is the probability that $x > 3$? Well, if I haven't told you any assumptions about $x$, the question is not well-formed and has no answer.  

So, to make sense of the question we could take a Bayesian approach and give some "prior" probability to $p_1, p_2$. One typical choice is to use the uniform distribution; or to use the Beta distribution if we have more information.